# Using a log-poisson model to predict mortality

Tags: python, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, statsmodels, mortality

I'm trying to build a GLM in Python that uses a log-poisson model from the statsmodels package to predict mortality rates.

I have a policy level dataset that, among other features, contains attained age, issue age, calendar year, duration, rate up group, factored, business type, gender, and impairment group that I want to use in the model.

So far, I've taken this dataset and created a summarized version of it, where the summarized version is grouped on the above features, and the sum of an exposure (i.e. the fraction of a calendar year an observation period covers) and total deaths for each of these groupings is calculated. I then create a new field called Mortality Rate, and is calculated as `max(ln(Deaths/Exposure),0)`. The result looks something like this:

| attained age | issue age | calendar year | duration | rate up group | factored | business type | gender | impairment group | exposure | deaths | Mortality Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1991 | 1 | 0-4 | Yes | Run off | Male | None | 0.586111 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1992 | 1 | 0-4 | Yes | Run off | Male | None | 0.413889 | 2 | 1.575304 |
| 1 | 1 | 1993 | 1 | 0-4 | Yes | Run off | Male | None | 0.416667 | 5 | 2.491595 |
| etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. |

Based on what I read on the statsmodels GLM documentation, I created some design matrices as follows:

```
y, X = dmatrices("Mortality Rate ~ attained age + issue age + calendar year + duration + rate up group + business type, data=summary_df, return_type="dataframe")
```

At this point I fit a GLM to my data as follows:

```
glm_poisson = sm.GLM(y, X, family=sm.families.Poisson())
res = glm_pois.fit()
print(res.summary())
```

I'm fairly certain I'm doing something wrong, because my pseudo R-squared value in the summary is around 0.006, and the residual plots and qq plots I made look awful. Does anyone see anything wrong with my approach? Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: poisson is a model for counts, The dependent variable should be deaths, and exposure can be specified through exposure keyword. log is captured through the link function and should not be used for the dependent variable

Comment: @Josef Thank you for your feedback. I've modified my equation to look like this
```y, X = dmatrices(deaths ~ attained age + issue age + calendar year + duration + rate up group + business type, data=summary_df, return_type="dataframe", exposure=np.asarray(summary_df['exposure'])``` Is that what you meant by "exposure can be specified through exposure keyword?"

Comment: Exposure is a keyword for GLM and not for dmatrices. Offset and exposure are handled by the model.